# I cannot email from django

Tags: python, django, email

Good afternoon,

I am trying to send an email from shell using Django. it is showing me an attribute error, please find here the code

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.emailBackend"

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_UNSER = "myemail@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "Password"
```

and in shell I do

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Asunto', 'Mensaje', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'testemail@outlook.com', fail_silently=False, )
```

and it is coming with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\….\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    return getattr(module, class_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp' has no attribute 'emailBackend'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 51, in send_mail
    connection = connection or get_connection(
  File "C:\Users\….\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 34, in get_connection      
    klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
  File "C:\Users\...\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 22, in import_string     
    raise ImportError('Module "%s" does not define a "%s" attribute/class' % (
ImportError: Module "django.core.mail.backends.smtp" does not define a "emailBackend" attribute/class
```

> > > I am not really sure why is coming with this error, I have change the security settings in my email. and I have follow the steps from tutorials and I am not sure with my error is.

THANK YOU :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you have misspelled `emailBackend`,

It is `EmailBackend`

[Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L12) is github link.

Answer (score 0):

The message says that the `to` argument must be either a list or a tuple, so it must use either a rounded bracket (in the case of a tuple) or a square bracket (in the case of a list):

The below is an example of using a tuple...

```py
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail

>>> send_mail('Asunto', 'Mensaje', 'myemail@gmail.com', '(testemail@outlook.com',), fail_silently=False, )
```